# Omitting the word "one"

Tags: omissibility

Do these sentences mean the same? Is one preferable to the other?

1. I think Ben is a robot. If he is, we should not talk to him anymore.
2. I think Ben is a robot. If he is one, we should not talk to him anymore.

Comment: If think 2 would be more appropriate in a context where some/many people might be suspected of being a robot, perhaps because there are (known to be) a few robot-people around (_one of those_), like in a science fiction movie. 1 would seem more appropriate for current times.

Comment: I think they're both acceptable, although "one" seems unneccessary and so I'd be tempted to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Both read well.  I would use (1) in emails/chat, everyday use because it is shorter, more efficient and more lazy.  I would use (2) in literature writing to clearly define meaning and ensure complete sentences, such as "I think Ben is a robot.  If indeed Ben is a mechanical entity then perhaps we should stop interacting with him.